# Slider gallery: video won't pause even when not displayed

Tags: reactjs, slider

So I've created a slider gallery in ReactJS from scratch. It is working perfectly except for the fact that if I play the video, it won't stop playing even if I move to the next image in the gallery. How can I pause the MP4 when the user has moved on to the next image? Below is my relevant code.

```
{dataSlider.map((obj, index) => {
      return (
            <div key={obj.id} className={slideIndex === index + 1? "slide active-anim" : "nothing"}>
                  {obj.type ? 
                        (<img src={obj.img}/> ) : 
                        (<video controls>
                              <source src={obj.vid} type="video/mp4"/>
                        </video>)
                  }
            </div>
            )
})}
```

My dataSlider JS file is formatted like follows:

```
const video = false;
const image = true; 

const dataSlider = [
    {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: "Battle for Los Angeles",
        text: "Competing at the Battle for Los Angeles tournament.",
        type: video, 
        vid: b4la
    },
    {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: "Group Photo",
        text: "Team photo at the Battle for Los Angeles tournament, where we competed with Queen of Hearts. ",
        type: image, 
        img: group
    },
    ...
}
```

I don't really know how to address this problem. I've tried searching for similar problems online but nothing that really helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to programmatically handle the video play/pause. Create your own Video component and pass whether to stop the video as a prop.

VideoContainer.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function VideoContainer({ isActive, src, type }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    if (!isActive) {
      ref.current.pause();
    }
  }, [isActive]);

  return (
    <video controls ref={ref}>
      <source src={src} type={type} />
    </video>
  );
}
```

Then in your code where you render the video, change video tag with VideoComponent file

```
{
  dataSlider.map((obj, index) => {
    return (
      <div
        key={obj.id}
        className={slideIndex === index + 1 ? "slide active-anim" : "nothing"}
      >
        {obj.type ? (
          <img src={obj.img} />
        ) : (
          <VideoContainer src={obj.vid} type="video/mp4" isActive={slideIndex === index + 1} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Edit: Check this updated example. I don't have your CSS so I had to change the logic to hide image. You can ignore that part. Play the video and click on next. Your video will stop playing.

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function VideoContainer({ isActive, src, type }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    if (!isActive) {
      ref.current.pause();
    }
  }, [isActive]);

  return (
    <video controls ref={ref}>
      <source src={src} type={type} />
    </video>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);
  const video = false;
  const image = true;
  const dataSlider = [
    {
      id: "eaa92d20-460d-4735-a57b-372ef906ddfc",
      title: "Battle for Los Angeles",
      text: "Competing at the Battle for Los Angeles tournament.",
      type: video,
      vid: "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "d92cf8b5-c64c-4fe5-af65-307eb71567b2",
      title: "Group Photo",
      text: "Team photo at the Battle for Los Angeles tournament, where we competed with Queen of Hearts. ",
      type: image,
      img: "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {dataSlider.map((obj, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={obj.id}>
            {obj.type ? (
              <div>{slideIndex === index && <img src={obj.img} width="300" height="300" />}</div>
            ) : (
              <VideoContainer
                src={obj.vid}
                type="video/mp4"
                isActive={slideIndex === index}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={() => setSlideIndex((prev) => prev - 1)}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setSlideIndex((prev) => prev + 1)}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-6i4FxVh0YbXCtxtqrFlG0H6FJRO4YQ5fyFH0JBdAAiqCt6/Q+jHMabMSC8FpESVSJZvnQ52dB2A8OD9SMk7buw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-I5GJQRKGdj2miDs8ComgARfiAQiZJo/43YasH22qtweoG+YRXLTDYegxC/vPgw/ERxRzww/F4l4+8UiMmI20sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Any idea why react has runtime error that says "The string contains invalid characters" when I implement this?

Comment: Can you show the error trace? I guess it's probably due to incorrect URL passed in src prop of VideoComponent.

Comment: The string contains invalid characters.
createElement@[native code]
createElement@http://localhost:3000/website/static/js/bundle.js:17525:51
createInstance@http://localhost:3000/website/static/js/bundle.js:18514:37
completeWork@http://localhost:3000/website/static/js/bundle.js:28129:46
completeUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/website/static/js/bundle.js:31888:32
...
@http://localhost:3000/website/static/js/bundle.js:1947:36

Comment: This seems to be a different issue. Seems that you issue in createElement tag somewhere.

Comment: I have added a live example. Run the snippet to check it. Also updated the previous code example, it should be VideoContainer and not VideoImage in the loop that renders the content. @PLWang

Comment: I fixed the error, it's working!